# A transformation of a probabilistic distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $\mu$ be a probabilistic distribution on $\mathbb{N}$.

Consider the following random process $F_i(\mu)$.

First we choose $i$ numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_i$ randomly with respect to distribution $\mu$.

Then $F_i$ outputs the minimal number in  $ \mathbb{N} \setminus \{x_1, \ldots, x_i \}$.

Is it true that there exist a polynomial $p$ such that for every $\mu$ and for every $\beta$ there exists $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\Pr[F_i(\mu) \text{ outputs }x] \ge \beta \cdot \mu(x)$ for some  $i <p(\beta + \log x)$?

Comment: $p(\beta+\log x)$ is rarely integer. You mean integer part or some inequality?

Comment: For $x=1$ your probability equals $(1-\mu(1))^i$, and for $\mu(1)$ close to 1 this is very close to 0, so your inequality looks impossible.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, thank you, I corrected my question